# DatePicker as inputView to textField doesn't update text

Tags: swift2, uitextfield, uidatepicker

I am using a UIDatePicker as input to a UITextField.

```
datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(DetailViewController.handleDatePicker(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```

I have got a few UITextFields that utilize the above UIDatePicker:

```
func handleDatePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {

        let timeFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        timeFormatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle

        for view in self.view.subviews {

            if view.tag == currentTagOfTextField {

                if let currentTextField = view as? UITextField {

                    currentTextField.text = timeFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This works fine when selecting a date other than what is currently displayed on the datePicker.
If user does not change the current displayed date on datePicker then the textField does not update with the date. Only if user actively changes the date forwards and backwards text field is updated.

I think it has to do with the `.valueChanged` in the action but not sure how to fix this.